# Select uitableview row programmatically

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uitableview

i have read a lot on this argument, i have tested this example that works:
[source code example](https://github.com/vikingosegundo/my-programming-examples/tree/master//TwoTableViews/). but this doesn't use storyboards (i don't know if this is the reason that make my project not working)
i have made another project using storyboard, the same sequence of instruction doesn't work...

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0];
    [firstController.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
    [firstTable.delegate tableView:firstTable didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

here is my project, is the same of the previous link, only adding viewDidAppear
[my not working project](http://www.2shared.com/file/6sBsVFB7/test.html)
can someone tell me what's wrong?
thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I tried to study your code downloading the project.The problem is that firstController.tableView is nil.
So fix it:

```
[firstTable selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath 
                        animated:NO 
                  scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```

Or assign firstController.tableView to the table view.

Answer (score 22):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
}
```

If you want the callback from the delegate:

```
if ([self.tableView.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:)]) {
    [self.tableView.delegate tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
}
```