# Set default selected cell in UITableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to set a default selectedCell and by default i mean that the cell has a specific `selectedCellBackgroundView`. However even though i've created a method for it, it does not seem to work. It does not show any `selectedBackgroundView` on the first cell? It works fine when i select a cell manually. What am i doing wrong?

**viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear tried both**

```
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
let cell = tableView!.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)! as UITableViewCell

applySelectionChangesToCell(cell)
```

**didSelectRowAtIndexPath**

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)! as UITableViewCell
    applySelectionChangesToCell(cell)

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(menuArray[indexPath.row].id!, forKey: "leagueId")

    self.sideMenuViewController.hideMenuViewController()

}
```

**applySelectionChangesToCell**

```
func applySelectionChangesToCell(cell:UITableViewCell) {

    let backgroundSelectionView = UIView(frame: cell.bounds)
    backgroundSelectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.1)
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = backgroundSelectionView
}
```

Comment: I think you need to actually select the cell as well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13808981/312594

Comment: I've tried selecting it aswell with no result `tableView!.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try this:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    // setup selectedBackgroundView
    let backgroundSelectionView = UIView()
    backgroundSelectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.1)
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = backgroundSelectionView

    return cell
  }

  override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
    tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .None)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes your code are not always write inside the UIViewController, Ex: subclass a UITableView

You just need a flag and easy for further reuse

```
final class CustomTableView: UITableView {

    private var rowDefaultSelected: Int = 0

    //..... 
}
```

And about UITableViewDelegate

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == rowDefaultSelected {
        tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .none)
        rowDefaultSelected = -1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In **Swift 4** this is the updated answer :)

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
  }

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    // setup selectedBackgroundView
    let backgroundSelectionView = UIView()
    backgroundSelectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.1)
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = backgroundSelectionView

    return cell
  }

  override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
    tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
  }
}
```

Basically NSIndexPath has been replaced for IndexPath .

Answer (score 0):

try this(Swift 5):

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
    tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
    }
```

This will select the first row in the first section of your table view when the view controller loads.